# Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have inherited an Angular 2 project. The part I'm having issues with is a `FormBuilder` form element. The element is a text field. The text field has a regex for validation. As soon as the field validates correctly, the error shows up in the console.:

> Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

I have absolutely no idea what the issue is.

Here is the part of the form builder that builds the element I'm talking about:

```js
RenewalDate: [
  this._datePipe.transform(this.product.RenewalDate, "dd/MM/y"), 
  [ 
    Validators.required, 
    Validators.pattern("^((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(2019|202[0-9]))$")
  ], 
  Validators.maxLength(10)
]
```

And here is the mark-up:

```html
<div>
    <label for="RenewalDate">Contract End Date*</label>
    <input type="text" #Next formControlName="RenewalDate" maxlength="10" 
        placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
    <label class="sh-error" *ngIf="productForm.controls.RenewalDate.hasError('pattern') 
        || productForm.controls.RenewalDate.hasError('required') 
        && (productForm.controls.RenewalDate.dirty 
        || productForm.controls.RenewalDate.touched)">
        *Please provide a valid date (DD/MM/YYYY)
    </label>
</div>
```

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Here is the error in full:

[image: Console error message]

Comment: Any other component trying to access `something.nodes`? Maybe hidden under `*ngIf="RenewalDate.valid"`?

Comment: I'm not overly familar with Angular, and I have no idea what 'nodes' is referring to.

Comment: I'd start with simply looking for the string `nodes` in the code: TS and templates.

Comment: There is no 'nodes' in the code.

Comment: So if you remove `Validators.pattern("^((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(2019|202[0-9]))$")]` you don't get an error?

Comment: I think If you could create stackblitz application with your form (may be other fields & logic stripped off but keeping submit button and logic intact) it would be helpful to analyze that.

Comment: @fridoo Yes, it looks that way. I have removed the regex, and now, as soon as you start typing into the text box, the error message appears.

Comment: @Trap What error message? I asked whether you **don't** get an error if your remove the regex. In general try removing code until you don't get an error any more so you can narrow the error down to one piece of code if possible.

Comment: @fridoo Sorry - I mixed up my words and couldn't edit it. So, I removed the regex and got the same error as soon as I started typing into the text box.

Comment: The code you are presenting works correctly (just the `Validators.maxLength` is in wrong place and caused a completely different error which was resolved when moving to inside the validators array). So when writing a question, please make sure that the code you are presenting reproduces the issue. Currently it does not, as I tested it and it worked fine. Please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz.